# Elliptic Curve $E/\mathbb{Q}$ with $\Delta_E^{1/3}$ a root of defining cubic

Tags: elliptic-curves

Consider the elliptic curve 
$$E'\colon y^2 = g(x) = x^3 + \frac{1}{432} .$$
One can check that the discriminant of $E'$ is $-1/432$, that $E'$ has complex multiplication, and that $(-1/432)^{1/3} = (-1/6 \sqrt[3]{2})$ is a root of $g(x)$. Hence there exists a CM elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that the cube root of the discriminant is a root of the defining polynomial.

My question is of the same flavor of this with added assumptions, in particular, we want 
$$E \colon y^2 = f(x) = x^3 + Ax + B$$ to be a non-CM elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ in Weierstrass form. Let $\Delta_E$ denote the discriminant of $E$, and for the time being, we want $\Delta_E$ to be a rational square. I want to know whether there exists such an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(\Delta_E^{1/3}) = 0$. The condition on the discriminant tells us that there are 3 real, distinct roots $f(x)$, which only seems to complicate matters. Any help and/or references would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the answer to your question is "no", i.e., there is no elliptic curve without CM with the specified property on the discriminant, and I was very close to prove it... Hopefully you can finish it up somehow. However, there is another CM curve with the same property, namely $E: y^2=x^3-1/16x$!

Let $E: y^2=f(x)=x^3+Ax+B$, for some $A,B\in\mathbb{Q}$ and discriminant $\Delta_E$, be such that $\Delta$ is a perfect square, and $f(\Delta_E^{1/3})=0$. Notice that this means
$$0 = \Delta_E +A\Delta_E^{1/3}+B.$$
If $A=0$, then $E$ has CM (with $j$-invariant equal to $0$), so let us assume that $A\neq 0$. Therefore, $\Delta_E^{1/3}=(-B-\Delta_E)/A\in\mathbb{Q}$. It follows that $\Delta_E$ is a cube in addition to a square, so $\Delta_E=\delta^6$ for some $\delta\in\mathbb{Q}$. Thus,
$$0 = \delta^6+A\delta^2+B$$
and so $B=-(\delta^6+A\delta^2)$. Moreover,
$$\delta^6=\Delta_E=-16(4A^3+27B^2) = -16(4A^3+27(\delta^6+A\delta^2)^2).$$
This condition defines a curve $C:\delta^6+16(4A^3+27(\delta^6+A\delta^2)^2)=0$ which happens to be of genus $1$. There are $4$ points that are easy to find:
$$[d,A,z]=[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1/2,-1/16,1],[-1/2,-1/16,1].$$
The first two correspond to $A=0$ and a solution with $z=0$, so we discard those two. The third and fourth correspond to $E: y^2=x^3-1/16x$, which is a curve with CM (with $j=1728$). Now, $C$ is of genus $1$ and using $P=[0,1,0]$ as the origin point, we can find a (surprisingly simple) Weierstrass equation
$$E': y^2=x^3+729$$
and a map $\phi: C\to E'$ given by
$$[243d^{10}z + 486d^6Az^4 + 9/16d^4z^7 + 135d^2A^2z^7,-2187d^{11} - 4374d^7Az^3 - 81/16d^5z^6 - 1215d^3A^2z^6,
-A^2z^9].$$

It turns out $E'$ has rank $0$ and torsion $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, generated by $R=(18,-81)$. The point $[1/2,-1/16,1]$ of $C$ maps to $R$ via $\phi$, and $[-1/2,-1/16,1]$ of $C$ maps to $-R$ via $\phi$. The map $\phi$ is not defined at $[0,1,0]$ or $[0,0,1]$. So the question is... are there points on $C$ that map to $\mathcal{O},2R,3R$, or $4R$? If so, there could be additional solutions to the question.

I leave here the Magma code I used:

> S := AffineSpace(Rationals(),2);
>
> f:=-16*(4*A^3+27*(d^6+A*d^2)^2)-d^6;
>
> f;
>
> C := Curve(S,f);
>
> Genus(C);
>
> P:=ProjectiveSpace(Rationals(),2);
>
> C:=Curve(P,-432*d^12 - 864*d^8*A*z^3 - d^6*z^6 - 432*d^4*A^2*z^6 - 64*A^3*z^9);
>
> PointSearch(C,100);
>
> E,phi:=EllipticCurve(C,C![0,1,0]);
>
> E;
>
> Rank(E);
>
> TorsionSubgroup(E);
>
> Generators(E);
>
> P:=phi(C![1/2,-1/16,1]);
>
> 2*P;
>
> a,b:=HasPreimage(2*P,phi);
>
> a,b;